# Computer restarted while code was running

Tags: r, object, environment, restart

For a few days now, I have been running a long code on RStudio. I discovered in the morning that during the night, the computer resarted. I know the line where it stopped, because of the files saved on my computer. I would like to keep running the code from where it was interrupted but the environment is now empty - is there a way to "recover" everything? Re-starting from scratch would take so much time...

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: There’s no way to recover the environment, no. For long-running code, what’s often done is to split the analysis into self-contained chunks with well-defined input and output, and store those values in intermediate data files. In fact, this approach is so frequent that there are a plethora of tools to formalise and automate it, e.g. the ‘targets’ package.

Comment: Is it possible to do it automatically on the long code that I have, for a next time? How would it work (never done this before)?

Comment: Not automatically, no. In fact, setting this up properly is not trivial. I suggest reading the walkthrough of the ‘[targets](https://docs.ropensci.org/targets/)’ package, this will give you an idea of what’s necessary to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way except for modifying the code to start processing data from where it ended.

In general, if one writes tasks that can run for so long, it's a must to split them to smaller chunks that do not have to be repeated, and write code for saving/restoring the state.